# Job DSL Pipeline Config Trigger

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to know how can i use Job Dsl to configure trigger "Trigger build remotely" a pipeline job.

I need input string as Authentication Token.
[image]

My sample code:

```
pipelineJob("PipelineJobs") {
  logRotator {
    daysToKeep(7)
    numToKeep(10)
  }
  concurrentBuild(false)
  parameters {
    stringParam('PHID',null,null)
    stringParam('SHA1',null,null)
  }
  triggers {

  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally that option is not a trigger, so you can't find it within the `triggers` context.

You need to use `authenticationToken` on the job level, see the [API Viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-authenticationToken)

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  authenticationToken('secret')
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore since version 1.70 of the jobs-dsl plugin (apparently due to [PR 1131](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/1131)). Whether it's a regression (the API viewer still shows the `authenticationToken` function) or intended is unclear to me.